Turbo Rails - TypeError: ya is not a function at ga
After updating my Ruby on Rails app, I encountered the following error when hovering over links, and Turbo is not working properly (it reloads the entire page instead of updating the body content):
TypeError: ya is not a function at ga (application-d5a03decd2bd9279296b1b2ff8e830402602a10d03729eb393ef1d31d14bb401.js:6:3019)
 at pi (application-d5a03decd2bd9279296b1b2ff8e830402602a10d03729eb393ef1d31d14bb401.js:6:3098)
 at Qn.canPrefetchRequestToLocation (application-d5a03decd2bd9279296b1b2ff8e830402602a10d03729eb393ef1d31d14bb401.js:20:37313)
 at #i (application-d5a03decd2bd9279296b1b2ff8e830402602a10d03729eb393ef1d31d14bb401.js:20:18978)
 ga @ application-d5a03decd2bd9279296b1b2ff8e830402602a10d03729eb393ef1d31d14bb401.js:6 pi @ application-d5a03decd2bd9279296b1b2ff8e830402602a10d03729eb393ef1d31d14bb401.js:6 canPrefetchRequestToLocation @ application-d5a03decd2bd9279296b1b2ff8e830402602a10d03729eb393ef1d31d14bb401.js:20 #i @ application-d5a03decd2bd9279296b1b2ff8e830402602a10d03729eb393ef1d31d14bb401.js:20

I am running the following build command:
"build": "esbuild app/javascript/application.js --bundle --minify --sourcemap --format=esm --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=/assets"
I updated the following in my Ruby on Rails application:
Ruby from 3.3.4 to 3.3.5
@hotwired/turbo-rails from 8.0.5 to 8.0.9
@hotwired/turbo from 8.0.5 to 8.0.6
Here is my application.js
import './src/init_jquery';
import './vendor/jquery-ui';

import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"

and here the init_jquery.js
import jquery from 'jquery';
window.$ = jquery;
window.jQuery = jquery;
$ = jquery;

If I don't minify my application.js file (which includes Turbo) it works fine.
I already tried deleting the cache
rails tmp:cache:clear
rails tmp:clear 
rails assets:clobber

Or running the build with (--keep-names) results in the same problem.
Or exclude hotwire from application.js build with (--external:@hotwired/turbo) results in 2Turbo:load funktion" not working anymore.
Update: When I use --tree-shaking=false, the error no longer occurs.

Remove the --minify flag so that you get a less obscure error message.
